# My PSTricks is broken: empty output from pst-vowel example

Tags: xetex, pstricks, linux

Consider the following example from the pst-vowel manual (http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/contrib/pst-vowel/pst-vowel.pdf):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tipa,pst-vowel}
\begin{document}

\begin{vowel}
\putcvowel[l]{\textipa{i}}{1}
\putcvowel[r]{\textipa{y}}{1}
\putcvowel[r]{\textipa{u}}{8}
\putcvowel[l]{\textipa{\textturnm}}{8}
\putcvowel{\textipa{\textturna}}{15}
\end{vowel}
\psset{arrowsize=.75ex, nodesep=.25ex}
\ncline{->}{v15}{v1}
\ncline{->}{v15}{v8}

\end{document}
```

This should produce a vowel diagram with three vowels and two PSTricks arrows. However, on my system (Sabayon Linux), when compiled with xelatex, it produces an empty page.

Interestingly, if I comment out the two \ncline commands, I get the expected diagram, obviously sans the arrows.

This must be a set-up problem on my end, but what is it? I have texlive-xetex and texlive-pstricks installed and I am not seeing any error messages in the xelatex output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/tipa.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-vowel/pst-vowel.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-node/pst-node.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.57  <2014/08/27> (tvz)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-site/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex  v1.35, 2014/08/04))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/vowel.sty)) (./test.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd) [1] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
 minimal.cls    2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
    tipa.sty    2002/08/08 TIPA version 1.1
 fontenc.sty
   t3enc.def    2001/12/31 T3 encoding
  ot1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
pst-vowel.sty    2009/04/24 pst-vowel Package version 1.0
pst-node.sty    2010/04/22 package wrapper for pst-node.tex
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
pstricks.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/08/27 v2.57 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2014/07/25 v4.03 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

pst-node.tex    2014/08/04 1.35 `pst-node' (tvz,hv)
   vowel.sty    2002/08/08 VOWEL Package version 1.1
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********

 )
Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

It also works properly when taking the latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf route, but I would greatly prefer getting this to work in xelatex as well (due to its improved font handling which I rely on).

What is wrong with my set-up?

**EDIT:** (I do not have the reputation to comment on your responses yet)
I have added the output when running with \listfiles. The same output shows when running under latex, however, (barring the obvious xetex.def<->dvips.def) and there it works. Could the problem therefore be in xelatex.def, or is this a red herring?

Comment: no problem with an up-to-date TL 2015 and also no problem with latest TL 2014 from. I am using Ghostscript 9.15. Try your example with the documentclass minimal instead and use \listfile and post your file list which can be found at the end of your log file

Comment: No problem with MiKTeX either.

Comment: @Phlox: If you are using Ghostsctipt newer than 9.10,
try 9.10. I remember that newer Ghostscript requires
newer xdvipdfmx.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: @Phlox You seem to have *two* accounts, you do not need reputation for comments of your question, but you need to be logged into the account, that was used for asking the question. I will flag the moderators for merging the accounts.

Comment: Account merging needs staff action: http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments by Akira Kakuto, downgrading ghostscript from 9.15 to 9.10 solves the issue.

Comment: xdvipdfmx in TeX Live 2015 supports Ghostscript 9.15, and 9.16.

Answer (score 0):

no problem with an up-to-date TL 2015 and also no problem with latest TL 2014. I am using Ghostscript 9.15. Try your example with the documentclass `minimal` instead and use `\listfile` and post your file list which can be found at the end of your log file